# Finding rotation that match two sets of points

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have two sets of points in 3D, up to 10 points each. Their translations and scales are such that, for both sets, the distance between each point and origin is 1. One set of points should map to the other set via a translation only. However, I don't know which point maps to which.

I have tried two things: Kabsch and ICP.

Kabsch requires:

- generate set of all matchings between two sets of points
- find R that maps one to the other
- return the matching and rotation R that has the smallest distances between the points

that is, for `pts1` and `pts2` two Nx3 numpy arrays:

```
indices = list(len(pts1))
min_dist = np.inf
best_rot = None
for matching in itertools.permutations(indices, len(pts1)):
    idx = list(matching)
    pts2_p = pts2[idx,:]
    # Kabsch to find best fit rotation with SVD
    R = best_fit_rotation(pts1, pts2_p)
    pts1p = R.dot(pts1.T).T
    # calculate distances between each pair of points
    d = distance(pts1p, pts2_p)
    rmsd = np.sqrt(np.mean(d**2))
    if rmsd < min_dist:
        min_dist = rmsd
        best_rot = R
```

This works, but it's quite slow for more than `N=6` points. This is mainly because there are `N!` permutations to consider, which is `~5000` for `N=7`.

For ICP, one typically does:

- find nearest neighbors of each point in the other set
- find best fit transform (like in Kabsch)
- calculate the average distance between the two sets of points
- repeat until the average distance is below a threshold

The problem with this is that, by default, two points in the first set can have the same point in the second set as their nearest neighbor. I still have to iterate through all the matchings (although this is faster because I don't have to calculate the rotation matrix, and re-calculate distances for each matching). However, the rotation matrices this approach provides are numerically incorrect. I am therefore wondering:

1. Is there a flaw in my logic for modifying ICP?
2. In any case, is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'd really like to correctly find the correct pairwise alignment between the sets up front without testing them all. One way would be to find an order for the points in the sets that's rotation- and translation-invariant. For example, you could order the points by their distances to the centroid of the set. If the two sets map 1-to-1 that should give you the correct pairing.

If there multiple points have the same distance to the centroid then you'll need to generate multiple pairings and test them all but hopefully that number will be much less than N!. In the worst case all points are equidistant from the centroid but I think in that case you have multiple correct solutions.

Speaking of multiple solutions, you don't necessarily need to check all N! (or optimally generated) pairings in order to minimize distance. As soon as you find the distance to be zero, or less than an acceptable threshold, you can just return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the point about `N!`. As for the centroids, all the points in both sets are 1 unit away from the centroid, so that won't work. But I will think about what other ways I could eliminate most of the `N!` possibilities.

Comment: You said they're one unit away from the origin. That doesn't mean they're uniformly distributed around it. If more points are on one side than the other the centroid will be not be located on the origin.

Comment: Oops, yeah, that's right!